# Creating modules within a single laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, module, composer-php, hmvc

I'm trying to make a bigger **Laravel 5.1** application and I'd like to have my code logically separated to smaller *modules* or *packages*.
So my application structure would be something like:

- app/
- config/
- ...
- modules/

  - module_1
  - ...
  - module_n

Eeach module should have own database migrations, seeds, views, controllers and *vendor/* folder with dependent packages.

I have already tried [caffeinated/modules](https://github.com/caffeinated/modules) with no success.

Currently I'm using [pingpong-labs/modules](https://github.com/pingpong-labs/modules), which seems to be a great solution, but the problem is laravel are searching for alias classes like 'HTML' or 'Form' in root `vendor/` folder and not in `modules/../vendor/` folder, even though I have registered them manually in Module Service Provider.
Let say I have `ModuleServiceProvider.php` in `modules/` folder which looks like:

```
/**
 * Boot the application events.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
   ...        
}

/**
 * Register the service provider.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    // These are located in modules/../vendor/ folder
    $this->app->register('Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider');
    $this->app->alias('Html', 'Collective\Html\HtmlFacade');
    $this->app->alias('Form', 'Collective\Html\FormFacade');
}
```

I appreciated any suggestions or help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all, make sure that those aliases (if already existing in the application) are actually being set. You might want to check the config/app.php and remove any facades or aliases that already use those and see if it begins working.

Comment: But I'd like to every module might be able to register its own facades locally. Not globally in app/config.php.

Comment: While I'm no expert on Laravel, the app is a global thing, that's how the IoC container works (what handles your binds, injections and aliases). If you want to make use of Facades in the same way Laravel does things, you'll be operating on the scope of a Laravel application. I'm not sure if you can, but you could try having each module pull in Laravel's IoC independently and let it handle things locally but I feel like that's unnecessary. Multiple IoC containers... not sure how that would affect performance or the app. It looks like you're trying to make Laravel into Symfony.

Comment: I've never used Symphony and I'm also new in Laravel as well as in PHP.
So having separated modules with own facades etc. are not possible within one global IoC?
So is there any possibility? I've seen https://github.com/AsgardCms has achieved something similar what I've wanted... but don't know how.